# Custom Markers does not appear - Google Maps JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hello I'm trying to have a custom markers using KML icons, the google map works fine but it does not show the custom markers. I'm currently using what I have learned from the Google Map API documentations, where did I go wrong here?

Here's my code.

```
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBSTRDm6eRdkpoVOB2VJVJgTCNgmcuDcq0&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initmap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 16,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.529133, 121.021747),
                mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
            });

            var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
            var testIcon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/';

            var icons = {

                evac: {
                    icon: iconBase + 'ranger_station.png'
                },

                warehouse: {
                    icon: iconBase + 'truckpng'
                }
            };

            var features = [
                {
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(14.529133, 121.021747),
                    type: 'evac'
                }
            ];

            features.forEach(function(feature) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: feature.position,
                    icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
                    map: map
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="initmap()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 1100px; height: 1000px"></div>
    </body>
```

Comment: [The posted code works for me (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/x8db92vs/1/)

Comment: Yeah it works fine on fiddle but I don't know why it doesn't appear on index page.

Comment: You are including the google maps API multiple times.  (I get this warning in the javascript console: `You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.`)

Comment: Oh I didn't notice it, but still the custom markers does not appear :/

Comment: In my fiddle? Or in your code?  You had a typo in `truckpng`.  If it is in your code, you will need to provide a [mcve] that actually exhibits your problem.

Comment: There is no div with id="map" in the posted code...

Comment: Oh sorry it was my mistake I didn't notice the "map_canvas" part. It works well now thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback function `initmap` is not the same as that called by the script `initMap` and the map ID was referred to incorrectly.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Google maps - KML Icons</title>
        <script>
            function initMap() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                    zoom: 16,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.529133, 121.021747),
                    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
                });

                var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
                var testIcon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/';

                var icons = {
                    evac: {
                        icon: iconBase + 'ranger_station.png'
                    },
                    warehouse: {
                        icon: iconBase + 'truckpng'
                    }
                };

                var features = [
                    {
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(14.529133, 121.021747),
                        type: 'evac'
                    }
                ];

                features.forEach(function(feature) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: feature.position,
                        icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
                        map: map
                    });
                });
            }
        </script>
        <script async defer src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBSTRDm6eRdkpoVOB2VJVJgTCNgmcuDcq0&callback=initMap'></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='map_canvas' style='width: 1100px; height: 1000px'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: and you had two calls to the initmap function - one on the body which worked and the other as the callback in the script tag which didnt work